# Way to find rows with a same ID and only keep one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a working query that will return some results(records) from my database, like:

```
123|John Williams|IL|M|06/01/2011|ACTIVE
124|Mary Haque|NY|F|TERMINATED|06/30/2011
124|Mary Haque|NY|F|07/01/2011|ACTIVE
125|Alex Chan|VA|07/01/2011|ACTIVE
126|Rob Kreb|VA|TERMINATED|06/20/2011
```

As you can see, the result is simply a list of customer records, while the last two fields indicate whether the member is active or terminated and associated active/terminated date.

The complication now is, as you can see for member with ID 124 (Mary Haque), she has two records, and for this kind of two-record customer, I only want to keep the row where the member is active while totally ignore her terminated history. So for example, the desired output for the above should be:

```
123|John Williams|IL|M|06/01/2011|ACTIVE
124|Mary Haque|NY|F|07/01/2011|ACTIVE
125|Alex Chan|VA|07/01/2011|ACTIVE
126|Rob Kreb|VA|TERMINATED|06/20/2011
```

as you can see, now Mary Haque only has her active information on the result. The above result is generate by a SQL "Select" query, but I couldn't simply append a "WHERE status=ACTIVE" to this query because I still want to keep the members that only has ONE record like Rob Kreb above even though he is terminated. I only want the filtering for TERMINATED member record to take place when a certain member has two records.

FYI, my current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_change WHERE CUSTOMER_LOGIN NOT IN(SELECT CUSTOMER_LOGIN FROM  customer_full WHERE CUSTOMER_LOGIN IS NOT NULL)
UNION
SELECT * FROM customer_change WHERE CUSTOMER_POINTS=0 AND CUSTOMER_LOGIN NOT IN(SELECT CUSTOMER_LOGIN FROM customer_full WHERE CUSTOMER_POINTS=0 AND CUSTOMER_LOGIN IS NOT NULL)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why are you storing the date as a string and not a date?

Comment: Fix the title to match your question pls.

Comment: Also, try not to ever use UNION, there is almost always a better way.

Comment: @jeffrey - that's a pretty ridiculous statement regarding `UNION`.  It has a place.

Comment: Are those `06/01/2011 ACTIVE` one column or two: `06/01/2011` , `ACTIVE` ?

Comment: @ypercube, I fixed it with pipe as separator, they are two fields.

Comment: @Robert: Where is the schema? I am having a hard time trying to understand why you are using the union there, too.

Comment: And why the `TERMINATED` and `ACTIVE` appear in two diferent fields, mixed with dates.

Comment: @Sher, sorry for the incomplete description. The last two fields have to be string. One is "Active" while the Other is "Terminated". If a member is active, then the Active filed shows the date when this member gets actived, then the terminated field won't have a date value since he is not terminated yet, a string "Active" will indicate that he is still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colX` and `colY` are the last 2 columns of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (your_UNION_query) AS p
WHERE NOT ( colX = 'TERMINATED'
          AND EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM (your_UNION_query) AS q
              WHERE q.id = p.id
                AND q.colY = 'ACTIVE'
            )
          )
```

Comment: I ran your query by putting the union query in the two FROM clauses, now the result list shrinks but there is still user with two rows appearing with one line that he show terminated. Maybe I was missing sth?

Comment: @Robert: Oops, my wrong. Editing the answer. Try it now (it should be `EXISTS` and not `NOT EXISTS`.)

Comment: :your solution is perfect. I am having another problem, can you look at my follow-up post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794346/difference-between-using-load-data-and-through-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
DELETE
FROM tablename
WHERE tablename.status = 'TERMINATED'
    AND tablename.id IN(SELECT
                          id
                        FROM (SELECT
                                t.id
                              FROM tablename t
                              GROUP BY t.id
                              HAVING COUNT(t.id) > 1) AS T1)
```

Assuming that id is the field refering to 124,125, etc.